# Function for logical table

Tags: r, function, operators, venn-diagram

So I have this function for logical (venn diagrams) calculation
but I cant make function universal for any dataframe of any size..

This function only work for provided dataframe (only four columns)

```
how_much = 5000000
A <- sample(how_much, replace = TRUE, x = 1:5) 
B <- sample(how_much, replace = TRUE, x = 1:5)
C <- sample(how_much, replace = TRUE, x = 1:5)
D <- sample(how_much, replace = TRUE, x = 1:5)

VennData = data.table(A, B, C, D)


Venn_Counts <- function(dataset, unique_number, operator) {
  message("Operator arrgument are: `==` or`<` or `<=` or `>` or `>=`")
  if(inrange(unique_number, 1, 35) ){
    dataset %>% as_tibble() %>% 
      mutate(A = (operator(A, unique_number)),
             B = (operator(B, unique_number)),
             C = (operator(C, unique_number)), 
             D = (operator(D, unique_number))) %>%
      count(A, B, C, D)
  }
  else {
    print("Unique number must be in range from 1 to 5")
  }
}


Venn_Counts(VennData, 2, operator = `<=`)
```

how would we make above function universal for dataframe that would have more columns?

for smaller objects we would get something like :
arguments setting is **unique_number = 3, operator = `==`**

```
count    A      B
 24     TRUE   TRUE
 20     TRUE   FALSE
 13     FALSE  TRUE
 43     FALSE  FALSE
```

when we can see that we have 24 observations where both A and B is equal to 3, 20 observations have A equal to 3 and B non equal to 3, 13 observations have A not equal to 3 and B equal to 3 etc...

Comment: Can you explain in words what is `Venn_Counts` supposed to do ?

Comment: alredy updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the scoped verbs from `dplyr`:

```r
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

how_much = 5000000
A <- sample(how_much, replace = TRUE, x = 1:5) 
B <- sample(how_much, replace = TRUE, x = 1:5)
C <- sample(how_much, replace = TRUE, x = 1:5)
D <- sample(how_much, replace = TRUE, x = 1:5)

VennData = data.table(A, B, C, D)


Venn_Counts <- function(dataset, unique_number, operator) {
  message("Operator arrgument are: `==` or`<` or `<=` or `>` or `>=`")
  if(inrange(unique_number, 1, 35) ){
    dataset %>% 
      as_tibble() %>% 
      mutate_all( ~ operator(.x, unique_number)) %>%
      group_by_all() %>% 
      count()
  }
  else {
    print("Unique number must be in range from 1 to 5")
  }
}


Venn_Counts(VennData, 2, operator = `<=`)
```

Answer (score 1):

We could compare the `dataset` with `operator` directly and group by all the columns and calculate the count.

```
Venn_Counts <- function(dataset, unique_number, operator) {
    message("Operator arrgument are: `==` or`<` or `<=` or `>` or `>=`")
    if(inrange(unique_number, 1, 35) ){
       (operator(dataset, unique_number)) %>% 
        as_tibble() %>% 
        group_by_all() %>% 
        summarise(n = n())
       }
   else {
     print("Unique number must be in range from 1 to 5")
   }
}
Venn_Counts(VennData, 2, operator = `<=`)

#   A     B     C     D         n
#  <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>  <int>
#1 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE     2
#2 FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE      3
#3 FALSE TRUE  TRUE  FALSE     1
#4 TRUE  FALSE FALSE TRUE      2
#5 TRUE  FALSE TRUE  FALSE     1
#6 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE      1
```

**data**

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1234)
how_much = 10
A <- sample(how_much, replace = TRUE, x = 1:5) 
B <- sample(how_much, replace = TRUE, x = 1:5)
C <- sample(how_much, replace = TRUE, x = 1:5)
D <- sample(how_much, replace = TRUE, x = 1:5)
VennData = data.table(A, B, C, D)
```